# How would i go about plotting the below time domain function in scilab?

Tags: plot, scilab, exponential

I want to plot a graph for an exponential function but I am completely lost as i have never previously used matlab or scilab.

I have been researching a bit and now know how to plot linear functions, but I don't know how to plot the exponential function. I tried and kept getting errors such as "inconsistent row/column dimensions". The equation is

[image]

Comment: Hi I can see you are new here, please update the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is all i have at the moment. The bulk of my work was to get that equation in that form from differential equations. The scilab part is the last part and as I haven't had any prior experience I had to ask somewhere for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do what you want on [0,1]. The errors you get are likely due to missing dot in product operator:

```
t=linspace(0,1,1000);
plot(t,2-2*t.*exp(-t)-2*exp(-t))
```